# How to Remove default button background MouseOver in wpf?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have three buttons on my Xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupToggleStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                     Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
        <RadioButton GroupName="LanguageGroup" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Button0}" 
             CommandParameter="English" Content="English" Foreground="White" Width="80"  
             Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="#0000ffff" Height="30" Margin="8,5,162,21" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="BlueViolet">
        <RadioButton.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RadioButton.Resources>
    </RadioButton>
  <Grid/>
```

But when I put mouse over my button, button's background changes to default windows gray background.
What's The Problem?
[Here is a photo of my buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3vGu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `ToggleButton` defines animations inside its `ControlTemplate` to control the e.g., checked and hover behavior/states. You will have to override the default `ControlTemplate` in order to implement your custom animations and triggers.

Additionally, you must also move the mouse over trigger to the `RadioButton` template too.

You can find examples of the default styles and templates at [Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or use the XAML designer (or Blend) to edit a copy of the elements template.

```
<Style x:Key="GroupToggleStyle"
       TargetType="RadioButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="BlueViolet" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
          <Border x:Name="Border"
                  CornerRadius="5"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>

          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Background"
                      Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="Border"
                      Property="Background"
                      Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">

              <!-- Target the border to allow local Background values on the templated control -->
              <Setter TargetName="Border"
                      Property="Background"
                      Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

In case you want to change individual buttons only, simply base the individual `Style` on the common base `Style` (but note that you have to remove the local `Style` assignment as the local value has a higher precedence than the implicit `Style`).

Comment: here I added code for one button. but according to image, there is code for three buttons. will your code work for every buttons

Comment: You can apply the Style to as many buttons as you like.

Comment: But the Border style that you have added to the button is no longer required.